# type conversion error, c#

Tags: c#

I am using Advanced Matrix Library in C#. NET@
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/AdvancedMatrixLibrary.aspx?msg=4042613#xx4042613xx.

library css file is like

```
using System;

namespace MatrixLibrary
{
public class Matrix
    {
      private double[,] in_Mat;
            public Matrix(int noRows, int noCols)
    {
        this.in_Mat = new double[noRows, noCols];
    }
            public Matrix(double [,] Mat)
    {
        this.in_Mat = (double[,])Mat.Clone();
    }

        public static double[,] Identity(int n)
        {
            double[,] temp = new double[n,n];
            for (int i=0; i<n;i++) temp[i,i] = 1;
            return temp;
        }

public static double[,] ScalarDivide(double Value, double[,] Mat)
    {
        int i, j, Rows, Cols;
        double[,] sol;

        try  {Find_R_C(Mat, out Rows, out Cols);}
        catch{throw new MatrixNullException();}

        sol = new double[Rows+1, Cols+1];

        for (i = 0; i<=Rows;i++)
            for (j = 0; j<=Cols;j++)
                sol[i, j] = Mat[i, j] / Value;

        return sol;
    }


}}
```

I am trying to get identity matrix and getting error of type conversion. Could some one please guide me.

```
Matrix id_mat = MatrixLibrary.Matrix.Identity(6);
```

Can't implicity convert typedouble[*,*] to Matrix.

But

```
Matrix B = new Matrix(4, 4);
 Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < B.NoRows; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < B.NoCols; j++)
                    B[i, j] = 2 * rnd.NextDouble();

Matrix E = Matrix.ScalarDivide(2, B);
```

It works and I can Have a matrix. Please guide me?

regards,

Comment: Your returning a double[,] but the variable your  assigning it to is of Matrix type. Without more code it's hard to say but you probably want to return a Matrix type filled in with the double array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error message.

You have a method that returns `double[,]` and you are trying to store the reference in a variable for `Matrix`. There is no implicit conversion from a multidimensional array of doubles to a Matrix.

To use that method, you would write

```
double[,] id_max = MatrixLibrary.Maxtrix.Identify(6);
```

If you actually need to store it as a `Matrix`, you need to define the appropriate conversion to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a 2D array "double[,]" and you're trying to assign it to a "Matrix".  There isn't an implicit conversion that does this.  Does Matrix have a constructor that accepts a "double[,]"?  Maybe you could use that.

**EDIT:**  You might also find that a different matrix library would suit you better than one pulled off of CodeProject.  Math.NET Numerics is a good one that I've used that's also open source:  http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need an implicit cast.

```
public static implicit operator Matrix(double[,] m) 
{
  // code to convert 
}
```